# JSON parsing and accessing data from Dictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift

```
{
 ac = 0; 
 storeLocation = "<null>"; 
 storeSizeSqFt = 1000; 
 tinNumber = testdummy4y58; 
 wirelessInternet = 0; 
}
```

for the above written response I have written code

```
func StoreInfo(notification : NSNotification){
        if let result = notification.userInfo{
            print(result)
            if let particularStoreInfo = result["data"] as? NSDictionary{
                print(particularStoreInfo)
                if let temp = particularStoreInfo["store"] as? NSDictionary{
                        print(temp)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have successfully traversed inside the dictionary but Now guide me how to save and access details inside Store Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

To access data from inside an [`NSDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class), you can use this method, assuming `temp` in your question is the dictionary you want to retrieve information from.

```
temp.objectForKey("ac") // Key can be of type AnyObject
```

The above will retrieve the information saved under the key "ac".

To store data in an `NSDictionary`, you must use [`NSMutableDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableDictionary) instead, which contains the method `setObject`.

Example of saving information:

```
var value = "This is the string I will save in the dictionary"
var dictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
dictionary.setObject(value, forKey: "Name of the Key")
```

UPDATED: Changed `setValue` example to `setObject`. See @vadian's comment for details.

Comment: Never use `valueForKey:` / `setValue:forKey:` unless you really need the KVC functionality.